# Find $k$ such that $F(x;k)$ is elementary.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing, elementary-functions

I’m trying to understand core concepts about the closure of the set of elementary functions. Specifically, i would like to adress the following problem:

Find the all the numbers $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the function $F$ defined by the indefinite integral:
$$F(x)=\int \text{sin}(x)x^kdx$$
is elementary.

When $k=0$ the integral is just the sine integral.
For the case $k=1$ is also a trivial matter, as:
$$\int \text{sin}(x)xdx=\text{sin}(x)-\text{cos}(x)x+c$$
Thus, it’s clearly elementary. Repeated integration by parts lets you find similar solutions for $k\geq 0$ in the form:
$$F(x)=p(x)\sin(x)+q(x)\cos(x)+c$$
where $\{p;q\}\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus, $F$ is elementary for $k\geq 0$.
However, i cannot prove anything for $k<0$, as that exceeds my skills on calculus. I know from other sources that the case $k=-1$ is not elementary, and my intuition says is the same for every $k\leq 0$…but, how to prove such a thing?

Comment: Once you know $\int \sin(x)\;x^{-1}\;dx$ and $\int \cos(x)\;x^{-1}\;dx$ are not elementary, you can again use integration by parts (and induction) to conclude all negative integer cases are not elementary.